# Calcular valor de acordo com as datas selecionadas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Eu tenho que fazer um código que faz o calculo de `Reais` de acordo com 2 datas informadas. Tenho 2 `inputs` do tipo `text` para informar uma `data` no formato `dd/mm/yyyy`. O input **A** é da `data inicial` e o **B** é a `data final`. O usuário irá informar no input A por exemplo 20/05/2015 e no input B irá ser 03/05/2015. A diferença então são 13 dias e preciso multiplicar por `10` (que seria o preço em Reais), assim totalizando `R$ 130,00` Reais. Quero chegar no seguinte, ao usuário informar as duas datas o calculo é feito automático e exibido em uma `<div>`. Não tenho nenhum código pronto, mas estou com extrema dificuldade em fazer esse código.

Answer (score 2):

Para calcular os dias é assim:

```
function diferencaEntreDias(dataIni, dataFim){//recebe a data no formato MM/dd/yyyy  
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;//Variável que representa um dia em milissegundos  
    var date_ini_ms = new Date(dataIni).getTime();//variável que representa a data incial em ms  
    var date_fim_ms = new Date(dataFim).getTime();//variável que representa a data final em ms  
    var diferenca = date_fim_ms - date_ini_ms;//diferenca, em ms, entre as datas  
    return Math.round(diferenca/ONE_DAY);//diferenca, em dias, entre as datas  
}
```

Para calcular é só fazer:

```
window.alert(qtdDias * 10);
```

lembrando que é um alert pra você ver o valor do calculo.

O exemplo para atualizar a DIV é esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function gravar(){
            var titulo = document.getElementById("txtTitulo").value;
            var subtitulo = document.getElementById("txtSubtitulo").value;
            var div = document.getElementById("divResultado");

            div.innerHTML = "<h1>" + titulo +"</h1>"+ "\n" + subtitulo;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <label>Título:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtTitulo"/>
        <label>Subtítulo:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtSubtitulo"/>
        <button id="btnEnviar" onclick="diferencaEntreDias(passeAsDatasAqui)" >Gravar</button>
    </div>
    <div id="divResultado">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Como você pode ver é um exemplo que você vai precisar entender pra montar ele corretamente mas essa é a base.

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar a biblioteca **[MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)** para fazer o *parse* e verificar quantos dias passaram.

```js
var inicial = moment('1/02/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    final =   moment('14/02/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
    diasPassados = final.diff(inicial, 'days');

alert('Dias passados: ' + diasPassados); // Dias passados: 13
alert('Valor do frete: R$' + (diasPassados * 10) + ',00'); // Valor do frete: R$130,00
```

```html
<script src='http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js'></script>
```

A função **`diff`** fornece diversas informações de diferenças entre datas. Quando utilizada enviando o argumento `'days'`, é retornado a quantidade de dias passados entre uma data e outra.

```js
function byId(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el)
};

function isNullOrEmpty(el) {
  return el.value == null || el.value == '';
}

var $inicial = byId('inicial'),
  $final = byId('final'),
  $frete = byId('frete'),
  $calcular = byId('calcular');

$calcular.addEventListener('click', function() {

  var valorFrete = '00';

  if (!isNullOrEmpty($inicial) && !isNullOrEmpty($final)) {

    var inicial = moment($inicial.value, 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
        final =   moment($final.value,   'DD/MM/YYYY');

    // isValid é uma função da própria biblioteca MomentJS
    // para verificar se uma data é válida.
    if (inicial.isValid() && final.isValid())
      valorFrete = final.diff(inicial, 'days') * 10;
  }

  $frete.innerHTML = 'R$' + valorFrete + ',00';
});
```

```html
<script src='http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js'></script>

<label for='inicial'>Data Inicial</label>
<input id='inicial' type='text' placeholder='10/02/2015' />
<label for='final'>Data Final</label>
<input id='final' type='text' placeholder='10/02/2015' />

<button id='calcular'>Calcular</button>
<p id='frete'></p>
```

Comment: Opa, obrigado já é meio caminho andado. Mas ainda falta uma coisa que eu acho que para mim será a mais díficil, que é a questão de só calcular quando o usuário preencher os dois campos de data **A** e **B**, como poderia fazer isso ? Está sendo o mais díficil agora

Comment: Inclui um exemplo simples, sem muitas validações. @AlissonAcioli